Differentiability of $\frac{(x - y) f'(x)}{f(x) - f(y)}$ away from poles when $y$ is not a critical point
Let $f: \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be three times differentiable and let $y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f'(y) \neq 0$.
With a lengthy manual calculation I could show the following:
$$
\frac{(x - y) f'(x)}{f(x) - f(y)} = 1 + \frac12 \frac{f''(y)}{f'(y)} (x - y) + \left(\frac23 \frac{f'''(y)}{f'(y)} - \frac12 \frac{f''(y)^2}{f'(y)^2}\right) (x - y)^2 + o((x - y)^2).
$$
That is, $\frac{(x - y) f'(x)}{f(x) - f(y)}$ is two times differentiable in a neighborhood of $y$ and the derivatives are as given. For the neighborhood one can choose $\{y\} \cup \mathbb{R} \setminus \{x \in \mathbb{R}: f(x) \neq f(y) \}$.
I therefore hypothesize that the following holds, which I can not show as my only strategy so far are explicit calculations with differential quotients:
Let $f: \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be $n+1$ times differentiable and let $y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f'(y) \neq 0$. Then $\frac{(x - y) f'(x)}{f(x) - f(y)}$ is $n$ times differentiable on the set $\{y\} \cup \mathbb{R} \setminus \{x \in \mathbb{R}: f(x) \neq f(y) \}$.
This result is so simple that I am shocked that I do not know a reference for it. Surely there must be a classical theorem of real analysis which implies it? I would really like to see a proof! I suppose a proof should also yield an explicit formula for the higher derivatives at $y$.
And of course, what about higher dimensions?
EDIT: I would like to remark that if $f$ is analytic, then for any $y \in \mathbb{R}$ the singularities of the function $\frac{(x - y) f'(x)}{f(x) - f(y)}$ are all removable and hence the function is also analytic.
EDIT 2: After a discussion with a friend it seems like the problem is not that difficult and the following strategy should work:
Consider the function
$$
g(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac{f(x) - f(y)}{x - y} &, x \neq y \\
f'(y) &, x = y
\end{cases} \,.
$$
I claim that $g$ is $n$ times differentiable in $y$. Then we can write
$$
\frac{(x - y) f'(x)}{f(x) - f(y)} = \frac{f'(x)}{g(x)},
$$
and since $f'$ and $g$ are $n$ times differentiable and $g \neq 0$ in a neighborhood of $y$, so is their quotient.
I think showing that the difference quotient is $n$ times differentiable should be possible by just applying Taylor's theorem liberally, but I have not yet figured out the details.

As for the the first part of the question, I would suggest using Lagrange's mean value theorem to showcase that $\frac{(x-y)f'(x)}{f(x)-f(y)} = \frac{f'(x)}{f'(\xi)}$ where $\xi \in [x, y]$. It follows that the initial function is as many times differentiable as you need.

@EgorLarionov $\xi$ depends on $x$ and $y$

@julio_es_sui_glace, it's not a function of $x$ or $y$ so you don't care when differentiating.

@EgorLarionov I would say $\xi$ is indeed a function of $x$ and $y$ and any mean-value theorem strategies will never tell you anything about the behavior of $\xi(x, y)$, so I don't think it can work this simply.

@RobertWegner, I may have acted rashly, I admit, to comment on that.  Do you think that in general the dependence of $\xi$ on the interval boundaries drastically affects the differentiability of the initial function?

Yes. Well, in reality one can probably choose $\xi$ to be regular most of the time, but when one uses the mean value theorem one does not get any information about $\xi$.

What is $ {x \in \mathbb{R}: f(x) \neq f(x) }$? Is it ${x \in \mathbb{R}: f(x) \neq f(y) }$?

@xpaul Yes, I edited it.

Lemma: Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be $n + 1$ times differentiable and let $y \in \mathbb{R}$ with $f'(y) \neq 0$. The function
$$
g(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{f(x) - f(y)}{x - y} & \text{if } x \neq y, \\
f'(y) & \text{if } x = y,
\end{cases}
$$
is $n$ times differentiable and
$$
g^{(n)}(y) = \frac{1}{n+1} f^{(n+1)}(y).
$$
Proof: We calculate
$$
\left( \frac{f(x) - f(y)}{x - y} \right)^{(n)}(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} (f(x) - f(y))^{(k)} \frac{(-1)^{n-k} (n-k)!}{(x - y)^{n+1-k}}
$$
$$
= - f(y) \frac{(-1)^n n!}{(x - y)^{n+1}} + \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \frac{(-1)^{n-k} (n-k)!}{(x - y)^{n+1-k}} \left( \sum_{j=k}^{n+2} \frac{f^{(j)}(y)}{(j-k)!} (x - y)^{j-k} + o((x - y)^{n+2-k}) \right)
$$
$$
= - f(y) \frac{(-1)^n n!}{(x - y)^{n+1}} + \sum_{j=0}^{n+2} f^{(j)}(y) \frac{1}{(x - y)^{n+1-j}} \sum_{k=0}^{n \land j} \binom{n}{k} \frac{(-1)^{n-k} (n-k)!}{(j-k)!} + o(x - y)
$$
$$
= f^{(n+1)}(y) \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n!}{k! (n+1-k)!} (-1)^{n-k} + (x - y) f^{(n+2)}(y) \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n!}{k! (n+2-k)!} (-1)^{n-k} \\
        + \sum_{j=1}^n f^{(j)}(y) \frac{1}{(x - y)^{n+1-j}} \sum_{k=0}^j \frac{n!}{k! (j-k)!} (-1)^{n-k} + o(x - y) \\
$$
$$
= - f^{(n+1)}(y) \sum_{k=n+1}^{n+1} \frac{n!}{k! (n+1-k)!} (-1)^{n-k} - (x - y) f^{(n+2)}(y) \sum_{k=n+1}^{n+2} \frac{n!}{k! (n+2-k)!} (-1)^{n-k} + o(x - y)
$$
$$
= \frac{n!}{(n+1)!} f^{(n+1)}(y) + \left( \frac{n!}{(n+1)!} - \frac{n!}{(n+2)!} \right) f^{(n+2)}(y) (x - y) + o(x - y) \\
$$
$$
= \frac{1}{n+1} f^{(n+1)}(y) + \frac{1}{n+2} f^{(n+2)}(y) (x - y) + o(x - y).
$$
Lemma: Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be $n + 1$ times differentiable and let $y \in \mathbb{R}$ with $f'(y) \neq 0$. The function
$$
h(x) = \frac{(x - y) f'(x)}{f(x) - f(y)}
$$
is $n$ times differentiable on $\{x: f(x) \neq f(y) \text{ or } x = y\}$ and
$$
h^{(n)}(y) = \frac{1}{f^{(1)}(y)} \left( f^{(n+1)}(y) - \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{n}{k} \frac{1}{n+1-k} f^{(n+1-k)}(y) h^{(k)}(y) \right).
$$
Proof: We write
$$
h(x) = \frac{f'(x)}{g(x)}.
$$
Then the previous lemma implies that $h$ is $n$ times differentiable on the set $\{x: g(x) \neq 0 \text{ or } x = y\} = \{x: f(x) \neq f(y) \text{ or } x = y\}$.
We have
$$
f^{(n+1)}(y) = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} h^{(k)}(y) g^{(n-k)}(y)
$$
which implies
$$
h^{(n)}(y) = \frac{1}{g(y)} \left( f^{(n+1)}(y) - \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{n}{k} h^{(k)}(y) g^{(n-k)}(y) \right)
= \frac{1}{f^{(1)}(y)} \left( f^{(n+1)}(y) - \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{n}{k} \frac{1}{n+1-k} f^{(n+1-k)}(y) h^{(k)}(y) \right).
$$

Great! But the calculation of the derivatives of $h$ is still a problem.

Yes... I dont think it is a very difficult problem, but I dont have time to try solving the iteration right now. I'd day one first makes an Ansatz for h as a linear combination of derivatives of f. Then one obtains an iteration for the coefficients. Usually Id expect one has to use generating functions somehow. It would be nice to see the explicit formula

Define
$$F_y(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{(x - y) f'(x)}{f(x) - f(y)} &, x \neq y, \\
1 &, x = y.
\end{cases}$$
Then $F_y(x)$ is three times differentiable at $x=y$. Now the Taylor expansion of $F_y(x)$ at $x=y$ is
$$ F_y(x)=1+F'_y(y)(x-y)+\frac12F''_y(y)(x-y)^2+O(|x-y|^3). $$
Now you can calculate $F'_y(y)$ first as following
$$\begin{eqnarray} 
F'_y(y)&=&\lim_{x\to y}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{(x - y) f'(x)}{f(x) - f(y)}\\
&=&\lim_{x\to y}\frac{(f'(x)+(x-y)f''(x))(f(x)-f(y))-(x - y) (f'(x))^2}{(f(x) - f(y))^2}\\
&=&\lim_{x\to y}\frac{(f'(x)+(x-y)f''(x))(f(x)-f(y))-(x - y) (f'(x))^2}{\bigg((f(x) - f(y))^2}\\
&=&\lim_{x\to y}\frac{(f'(x)+(x-y)f''(x))(f'(y)(x-y)+\frac12f''(y)(x-y)^2+O(|x-y|^3))-(x - y) (f'(x))^2}{(f(x) - f(y))^2} \\
&=&\lim_{x\to y}\frac{(x-y)f'(x)(f'(y)-f'(x))+\frac12f'(x)f''(y)(x-y)^2+O(|x-y|^3))}{(f(x) - f(y))^2} \\
&=&\lim_{x\to y}\frac{f'(x)\frac{f'(y)-f'(x)}{x-y}+f''(x)f'(y)+\frac12f'(x)f''(y)+O(|x-y|))}{\bigg(\frac{f(x) - f(y)}{x-y}\bigg)^2} \\
&=&\frac{f''(y)}{2f'(y)}.
\end{eqnarray}$$
You can perform the same for $F''_y(y)$.

Yes, I did such a kind of calculation too. But generalizing it to $n$ derivatives (rigorously) is tricky. At least I don't see it, I haven't been able to work out the details yet.

I doubt that there is a simple way to calculate n-th derivatives.

I think it is possible by writing g as a product of $f(x) - f(y)$ and $\frac{1}{x - y}$ and applying the general Leibnitz rule to get a formula for $g^{(n)}(x)$. Then use Taylor expansions in order to show that a derivative exists at $y$.

see my answer above, you can actually calculate it.
